# How can grunt extract the JSON object when the file assigns the object to a variable

Tags: javascript, json, gruntjs

I am trying to process the JSON objects cleanly but the JSON is assigned to a variable like this:

```
var test = { "foo" : "bar" };
```

I can use a file structures like this:

```
{ "foo" : "bar" }
```

And grab the JSON like this:

```
var jsonfile = grunt.file.readJSON(source)
```

But I need to automate this and preserve the current file structure.

Comment: Well, `var test = { "foo" : "bar" };` is not JSON, it's JavaScript. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to read the objects into my custom grunt task.

Comment: When I remove the variable assignment it is compatible with grunt.file.readJSON so I would consider the syntax very close here. I just want to make the import work when there is a variable assignment to the object rather than manually removing the variable assignments.

Comment: Seems like `var jsonfile = grunt.file.readJSON(source)` does that. *edit:* So the issue that you don't want to manually edit your files? You could write a one time script which edits your files.

Comment: You get this error if the source file has a variable assignment and you try to readJSON `file (Unexpected token v). Use --force to continue.`

Comment: Well, sure, as I said, you have JavaScript. JavaScript is not JSON, so you cannot use `readJSON` to read that file. If you want to use `readJSON`, make sure you have JSON, not JavaScript. It seems like you want to use `readJSON` without changing the files, but that's not possible.

Comment: I think you are missing my point I know that. I am trying to read a javascript object into my custom grunt script. I can read JSON if I edit the source. I need to automate a process that reads the file and processes the Javascript Object. It becomes a JSON compatible parse if I manually edit but that is not what I want to do. I want the grunt script to read the file as either a library or parse out the object.

Comment: So you are looking for something like `var str = fs.readFileSync('...', 'utf-8'); var data = JSON.parse(str.substr(str.indexOf('{'), str.lastIndexOf(';')));` ? Assuming of course the object literal would also be valid JSON.

Comment: great I knew it had some syntax related to filesystem

Comment: That's node, not grunt: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html. I would advice against doing this though. It's error prone and harder to maintain.

Comment: so no way to include external javascripts into a grunt task?

Comment: You can `require` any file you like as long as it exports something. Grunt is just a library running on Node. You can do whatever Node can do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80710/discussion-between-jack-shultz-and-felix-kling).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I could not find a way to include the javascript file into my grunt task. So what I did instead was read the file as a literal string.

Then using regex I removed the parts of the string representing a variable assignment. Finally I could parse the string as an object

```
  var test = grunt.file.read(source),
  re = new RegExp('var?.test?.=|;','gi'),
  test = JSON.parse(test.replace(re, ""));
```

Comment: Felix King had the best solution - just make sure your JS file exports something and then `require` your JS file at the top of your grunt file, just like you've `require`'d all of your other grunt plugins.

Comment: Well it did not work when I tried that. This did the trick however.

Answer (score 0):

FelixKing's solution realized:

```
//somefile.js
var someJSONObject = {
    SOME_KEY: "VALUE";
};

module.exports = someJSONObject;

//Gruntfile.js
var json = require('somefile');
console.log(json.SOME_KEY); //logs "VALUE"

module.exports = function(grunt) {
  //...rest of grunt file
}
```

Way more maintainable (and way more flexible) than parsing "var =" out of a raw string with RegEx. You're not limited to just JSON anymore, but any JavaScript.

Just to pre-empt any concerns you have about re-using a JS file for multiple purposes (so `module` might not be defined in `somefile.js` when it's not in a node environment), you can do this:

```
    //somefile.js
    var someJSONObject = {
        SOME_KEY: "VALUE";
    };

    //CommonJS export syntax
    //don't do anything if module.exports is not in scope
    if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
        module.exports = someJSONObject;
    }
```

Comment: I agree this looks more maintainable, I don't know what I did differently, but when I tried that, the variable I assigned the 'someJSONObject' only had null.

Comment: @JackShultz - my bad, the line in the Gruntfile.js should have read: `require('somefile');`